# Display paging in Horizontal list in flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, gallery

I need to display set of images in horizontal list. The list needs to be controlled with next and previous buttons. Moreover I need to display paging showing no of images per page below the list.

Any help as how to do it

Comment: Yeah, have you checked out google?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer the following document

1)[Pagination 1](http://www.riaxe.com/blog/demo/pagination/)

2) [Pagination 2](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Pagination_in_Flex-9263.html)

It might be helpful to u.